# JQuery Update values by ID and similar id

Tags: jquery, input

I'm trying to update values of hidden fields with those of their similar inputs. I have missed something as it is not working. Here is the code.

```
function livecntupdate() {
    $('input').each(function(){
        $(this).val($('CNT' + this.id).val())
    });
}
```

Marvellous

Comment: `$('#CNT' + this.id).val()` i assume you are selecting by id, if yes then you are missing the **#**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing hash `#` there needed for the `id`:

```
function livecntupdate() {
    $('input').each(function(){
        $(this).val($('#CNT' + this.id).val())
    });
}
```